# python how to identify block html contain text?

Tags: python, html, dom, extract

I have raw HTML files and i remove script tag.

I want to identify in the DOM the block elements (like `<h1> <p> <div>` etc, not `<a> <em> <b>` etc) and enclose them in `<div>` tags.

Is there any easy way to do it in python?
is there library in python to identify the block element

Thanks

UPDATE

actually i want to extract the html document. i have to identify the blocks which contain text. For each text element i have to find its closest parent element that are displayed as block. After that for each block i will extract the feature such as size and posisition of the block.

Comment: Look up `beautifulsoup` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: any decent search engine would provide you with an answer to this question...

Comment: you should accept an answer if it was useful

Answer (score 3):

You should use something like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

Have a look at their docs: [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

You should find what you are looking fore there. If you cannot get it to work, consider asking a more specific question.

Here is a simple example, how you cold go about this. Say 'data' is the raw content of a site, then you could:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data) # you may need to add from_encoding="utf-8"or so
```

Then you might want to walk through the tree looking for a specific node and to something with it. You could use a fct like this:

```
def walker(soup):
    if soup.name is not None:
        for child in soup.children:
            # do stuff with the node
            print ':'.join([str(child.name), str(type(child))])
            walker(child)
```

Note: the code is from [this great tutorial](http://makble.com/parsing-and-traversing-dom-tree-with-beautifulsoup).

Comment: Have you looked at beautiful soup? I'll update my answer with a link to a tutorial on how you can parse the DOM tree.

Comment: @KimHyesung any luck with that?